# There's no toolbar

Tags: bug, status-completed, editor

I was about to ask a question but the toolbar is gone and I cannot upload the image to post the question. It's not the case on other SE sites, not even in meta.CS.

[image]

Comment: It appears the problem does exist on other SE sites - but only those that use MathJax. So it seems to somehow be related to the problems that MathJax is having.

Comment: @sepp2k: Yes, that might be the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears this was connected to the MathJax outage, which has now been corrected.